# Ionic 4 change background dynamically of dynamical variables

Tags: ionic4

I'm building a quiz app just for fun. But I'm not getting what I want.

Basically, I have a question and answers (a-e options).

When I click a answer, I want to change the background (card) dynamically just for the selected. If was wrong, change this color to red and the correct one for green.

Simplified html

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12" style="padding: 0;">
         <ion-card class="card__wrapper card__{{answer.option}}" *ngFor="let answer of question.answers" tappable (click)="chooseAnswer(answer)" [style.backgroundColor]="answer.is_correct ? correct : 'color'+answer.option">
              <ion-card-content class="card__content">
                   <ion-row>
                       <ion-col size="2" style="padding: 0;">
                           <div class="option__wrapper">
                               <p class="answer__option">{{answer.option}}</p>
                           </div>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col size="10" style="padding: 0; margin: auto;">
                            <p style="text-align: left; margin: 0;"[innerHTML]="answer.description"></p>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Simplified .ts

```
public correct: string = '#fff';
public wrong: string = '#fff';
public slidePage = '0';

public colorA = '#fff';
public colorB = '#fff';
public colorC = '#fff';
public colorD = '#fff';
public colorE = '#fff';

chooseAnswer(answer) {

    if (answer.is_correct) {
        this.correct = '#00e676';
    } else {
        switch (answer.option) {
            case "A":
                this.colorA  = 'red';
                break;
            case "B":
                this.colorB  = 'red';
                break;
            case "C":
                this.colorC  = 'red';
                break;
            case "D":
                this.colorD  = 'red';
                break;
            case "E":
                this.colorE  = 'red';
                break;
        }
        this.correct = '#00e676';
        
    }
}
```

So there are two cases:

1. Select correct answer

   Set background of the selected answer to green
2. Select wrong answer

   Set background of the selected answer to red and set background of the correct answer to green.

Comment: In ngstyle first you put condition then ? Firstvalue to see  then : else.. that mean ngstyle="isanswer ? 'Green' : 'red'".

Comment: @MostafaHarb Didn't work :(

Comment: Edit you answer on how you made it... for sure you made it in wrong way.

Comment: @MostafaHarb Oh, now it worked, but it shows the answer before I click

Comment: Its related to your function

Comment: @MostafaHarb Could you help me please?

Comment: In else , remove this.correct, and instead of it add default inside case and inside style.backgroundcolor=anser.iscorrect ? correct : this.color . And instead of using colora/b/c , put it just color, and inside switch case assign to it the color of a , b , c...

Comment: @MostafaHarb Yeah, but if I do that, all the wrong answers are in red, but I just want it to be in red the selected wrong answer

Comment: Yes when you put this.color = the normal color in default then it will always show normal color and if answer.waswrong then in switch it will take red and if answer.iscorrect then it will be green.